# How to reset $dirty in form

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I am facing one issue while using **$dirty** in my application form.

The issue is once you change the form field,value of **$dirty** will get set to **true**
but now when you undo your changes it's not resetting **$dirty** value to **false**.

We can reset the **$dirty** value to **false** manually but afterwards when you again change your form field values **$dirty** won't change its value to **true**. According to my observation it set **$dirty** value of every field in your form by placing ng-dirty class. Even if you remove that class it is not affecting **$dirty** behavior.

```
// Please find below attached Fiddle for code reference
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rpTen/206/).

Answer (score 69, accepted):

What you are looking for is $setPristine(). You'll find it in the docs here: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController

When a form first loads on the page it is in a state called pristine. You'll find that form.$pristine is true and form.$dirty is false. Once any changes have been made to any element that has an Angular binding, those values are reversed. While you can reset the form input values to their original state, doing so does not change either Angular form state. Making a call to form.$setPristine(); sets those form values back to their original state.

Comment: Would you please give me Fiddle example for the same

Comment: Thanks @MBielski :) I'll check it my application and let you know :)

Comment: I've seen it where I create a form, and then somehow in loading it up the $pristine state gets set to false, even though the values haven't been changed by the user.  If I do a $setPristine, am I basically saying, "the way I have this form set up is to be considered pristine" or am I saying, "go through the form and change all the controls back to their original values" ?