# setting AngularJS form to Pristine

Tags: html, forms, angularjs

I have a form...

```
<form name="myForm" class="form" ng-submit="submit()" novalidate>
    <input type="text">
</form>
```

Then I want to reset my form to pristine

```
$scope.myForm.$setPristine(true);
```

But it is not working, it keeps it cannot set pristine of undefined.

Comment: where is the controller declared?  BTW, `$setPristine` will not clear the form, you have to do that by clearing the `$scope` properties.

Comment: All depends upon where are you calling it from? The myForm itself is not available.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reset $dirty in form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22990923/how-to-reset-dirty-in-form)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is copy old value and reset it.
There is example for you.[form reset example](http://www.angularjshub.com/examples/forms/formreset/)